# Simple app crash on iPhone simulator/ Mac OS 10.8.4

Tags: macos, xcode4, crash

This morning, after updated the Mac OS on my Mac to 10.8.4, I wrote some code the Xcode 4.6.2 then pressing the Run button to compile. (You know, I don't have stop the simulator, just press the Run button to compile and run.). And boom, app crash :(, I try some others that're Ok on 10.8.3 but no luck, still crash.
I found out some weird log in the Console.Do you know how to solve it?

```
6/5/13 10:25:34.266 PM installd[1174]: 0xb0219000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app user.ApplicationDemo

6/5/13 10:25:34.280 PM installd[1174]: 0xb0219000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.02s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.01s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.03s

6/5/13 10:25:34.280 PM lsd[1185]: updating identifier store

6/5/13 10:25:34.281 PM lsd[1185]: Attempting to store identifiers file

6/5/13 10:25:34.538 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0x435a]) Conflict with job: UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0xfedc] over Mach service: user.ApplicationDemo

6/5/13 10:25:34.538 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0x435a]) Conflict with job: UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0xfedc] over Mach service: user.ApplicationDemo.UIKit.migserver

6/5/13 10:25:34.543 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0x435a][1221]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...

6/5/13 10:25:34.606 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0xfedc][1212]) Exit timeout elapsed (1 seconds). Killing
6/5/13 10:25:34.816 PM com.apple.debugserver-199[1222]: debugserver-199 for x86_64.

6/5/13 10:25:34.817 PM com.apple.debugserver-199[1222]: Listening to port 30475...

6/5/13 10:25:34.919 PM com.apple.debugserver-199[1222]: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.

6/5/13 10:25:35.833 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0xfedc][1212]) The following job tried to hijack the service "user.ApplicationDemo" from this job: UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0x435a]

6/5/13 10:25:35.834 PM ImageWareDemo[1221]: GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort Couldn't register user.ApplicationDemo with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code (1100).
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

6/5/13 10:25:38.606 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[272]: (UIKitApplication:user.ApplicationDemo[0xfedc][1212]) Job has not died after being killed 4 seconds ago. Simulating exit.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will solve your problem :)
http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/

Answer (score 2):

The new update has been released which solves the sigbart issue. Its just a 60 mb update.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the simulator does not close the process correctly on some occasions. If you check Activity Monitor after you stopped the run via XCode and you still see the app process running, kill it via Activity Monitor and rerun from XCode. I found that this solves the crashing. Apple should fix this as soon as possible IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I think Apple will push an Xcode update after WWDC 2013 :)